# Displaying the sum of two Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, html

The output in the result field is showing NaN for the grandTotal function in the following JavaScript and HTML codes. Please assist to identify the error.

```js
function firstSum(){ 
  subPay=()=>{
   let comPay = document.getElementById('totPay').value;
   if (comPay > 215000){return (comPay - 215000)*0.25;}
    else {return comPay*0.15;}
   }
  document.getElementById('result1').value = subPay();
  }

 groPay=()=>{
  groEstimate=()=>{
   let comPay = document.getElementById('totPay').value;
   if (comPay > 220000){return (comPay - 220000)*0.33;} 
   else {return comPay*0.16;}
  }
 document.getElementById('result2').value = groEstimate();
 }

function grandTotal(){
  var allPay;
  allPay = firstSum() + groPay();
  document.getElementById('result').value = allPay;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="totPay" type="number" placeholder = "groPymt">
  <input type = "button" onclick = "grandTotal()" value = "Submit">

  <div><input type="text" class="totsum" id="result1"></div>
  <div><input type="text" class="totsum" id="result2"></div>
  <div>Result: <input type="text" id="result"></div><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Your functions `firstSum` and `groPay` don't return any value; either capture the retuned values of the internal functions `subPay` and `groEstimate` and return them, or drop the internal functions altogether (keeping their code, of course), as they don't seem to have any intrinsic value.

Answer (score 1):

You should either return the values at the end of `firstSum` and `groPay` or change `grandTotal` to something like

```
function grandTotal(){
  firstSum(); groPay();
  const fs = document.getElementById('result1').value;
  const gp = document.getElementById('result2').value;
  document.getElementById('result').value = fs + gp;
}
```